# determine if you're checked or unchecked

Tags: c#

In C#, is there any way to detect in code if the currently running block of code is running in checked or unchecked mode?

For example - if you have a method in a library to be used by others, and you want to decide whether or not to overflow an arithmetic operation you're performing on a custom data type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether a given method is using checked or unchecked operators has nothing to do with the callers.  It's known statically at compile time.  There is no way to check it dynamically because there's no need or point, it can't change dynamically.

As long as you compile your library with the checked/unchecked setting that you want, or use checked/unchecked blocks in your code as you want, then your code will be fine and there won't be any way for any caller of your library to change the operators you are using.

If you *want* a consumer of your library to be able to determine whether you use checked or unchecked operations then you're going to need to provide multiple methods (one checked and one unchecked), distribute two versions of the project, one compiled as unchecked and one checked, or something along those lines.  There's no way to change the code that the arithmetic operators is bound to at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You could run an overflow operation in a `try`...`catch` and see if you get an exception, but that is likely to be very slow. Also, the C# language specification says that checked/unchecked are local to a method, and not to function calls made outside the method.

Of course, if you are trying to make a user-defined numeric type behave like built-in arithmetic, that isn't terribly helpful.